Keynote video lag
I have been experiencing some issues with Keynote videos. I make presentations that included different audio and video sources, but every once in a while a video will simply not play and appears only as an image.
I can't use any of the shortcuts to make it play, fast forward or anything. The only way I can make it play is if I exit and start the presentation all over again, then it plays but another could suddenly start lagging. Does someone know how to fix this issue?
It's not one specific video that lags it's always a different one each time I play the same presentation (this problem happens throughout multiple different presentations so I know it's not one of my videos or one of my presentations that's the problem.
In case it helps I use an iMac to make them and play them both on my iMac and a MacBook and the same problem occurs, both are fully up to date.

What format are these audio/video files? How many are in the Keynote presentations (a few, a lot)? What are the file sizes of these files (especially the video files?) Are the audio files .MP3 files or video files with just an audio track?

hii thank you for answering! The video format is mp4 and the audio is from the video and an added aifc file throughout the slides. There are a lot of videos like a good 10-20 because each one is very short (always less than a minute long). I thought about the fact that maybe there are too many videos but our professor asked for us to do it in this specific way so I can't change that and am hoping to find a solution to the lag instead. Thank you for your response regardless!! it means a lot
